# GCC throws an error for initializing the structure members

Tags: c, gcc

I have this template in headerfile.

```
typedef struct ufdm_proactive_cc_glob_s {
    ufdm_procc_timestamps_t *procc_timestamps;
    uint32 procc_init_count;
} ufdm_proactive_cc_glob_t;
```

I allocate memory for this in a C source file as follows:

```
ufdm_proactive_cc_glob_t ufdm_procc_globals;
```

I access members of this structure and assign values to them as follows:

```
ufdm_procc_globals.procc_init_count = 1;
ufdm_procc_globals.procc_timestamps = NULL;
```

I received the following error.

> test.c:41:21: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before '.' >token

What is the reason for this error?

Comment: First, that's not a template.  Second, I don't know what you mean by _gmake throws an error_; that's a C program.  Why are you trying to give it to make?  Make is not a compiler.  Please show the command you ran and the _exact_ errors you got (cut and pasted with formatting) don't paraphrase error messages.  Then we can help.

Comment: Makefile invokes gcc to compile the source files. I commented the initializations, code compiles completely fine.

Comment: You cannot write assignments such as `ufdm_procc_globals.procc_init_count = 1;` outside of a function. If you want to give the members of `ufdm_procc_globals` initial values, do it in the definition: `ufdm_proactive_cc_glob_t ufdm_procc_globals = { .procc_timestamps = NULL, .procc_init_count = 1 };`.

Comment: But why should I not initialize structure members separately in global scope? Why is it not allowed? I am not declaring it twice but initializing it with different values. I think it's allowed.

Comment: The compiler disagrees with you, @Harish, and so does the C standard.  You can't write assignments outside functions, and you can't initialize a variable with multiple assignments like that (using initialize in the technical sense — you can assign value to create a useful variable, provided the assignments are inside a function).  An initializer has a specific syntax — see [§6.7.9 Initialization](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9) in the C standard.  WIshful thinking in C will lead to frustration — for you and for those who help you.

Comment: *Why is it not allowed?* -- Because it would needlessly complicate the language grammar. There is already a way to initialize struct members. Use it.

Comment: This is not initialisation. This is assignment. Assignment is a kind of statement. Statements are not allowed outside of functions.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLeffler for detailed explanation. Thanks others.

Comment: Assignment is not allowed at file scope because it would require evaluation which is a type of code execution. This would lead to problems of ordering of the evaluation if multiple assignments are used. There would be no way to synchronize evaluations between different translation units. This is a huge problem in C++ where initialization and deinitialization at file scope is allowed. To simply life C committee decided to disallow any runtime evaluation before `main()` thus disallowing assignments at file scope.